# Problem with fonts after site migration - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration

I just finished my new shop site. Testing version was at subdomain https://new.zapproject.pl and now I transfered it to main domain https://zapproject.pl but after testing page speed in GTmetrix I noticed problems with fonts - they are still loading from old url.

I changed all urls from https://new.zapproject.pl to https://zapproject.pl in Wordpress database with Better Search Request plugin. The same change I made in Elementor plugin and Settings -> General in Wordpress.

I am using now Wordpress v. 5.3.2 with WooCommerce plugin v. 3.9.2 and Porto Theme v. 5.2. As site builder I am using Elementor v. 2.9.3.

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Here you can see GTmetrix waterflow for the site -> https://gtmetrix.com/reports/zapproject.pl/RXBTnBQO

Comment: Do you have any caching plugin installed?

Comment: Looks like you have WP-Rocket installed. You need to clear the entire contents of the cache on your new site and then make sure that the the cache is writeable by the web server. You should temporarily deactivate any caching plugins to check if this is the actually the case.

Comment: Problem SOLVED! WP Rocket was the issue. I cleared all and regerate CSS and now everything looks good. Thanks!